# ArrayAdapter BluetoothChat

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I need a bluetooth transmission in my App. Therefor I used parts of the BluetoothChat Project of the android SDK. I can already connect to other devices and send data. Now i have go get the data on the other device.  If I am right, the data is stored in the mConversationArrayAdapter which is an object of the ArrayAdapter. 
But how do i get the Data out of the Arraydapter? What Methods do I have to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getItem(position), doing it getCount() times.
Or you can write own adapter, that extends, for example, BaseAdapter.

Comment: Now I get the an Error if I try to connect. It says:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: That means your adapter is empty. You should check the count before you start getting items.